# Pause directory until after unzipping is complete

Tags: apache-camel

I have a ZIP file with multiple files about 1GB each. Unzipping is done by one route (Route1) that polls the download directory and saves files to the extract directory. Another route (Route2) polls the extract directory to process the files.

These files are supposed to be processed in a certain sequence (Route2 uses sortBy when getting the files). Route2 immediately picks files that are still being unzipped before all the files are available.

How can i pause Route2 from processing until after Route1 is done unzipping the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you write a done-file in your first route once the unzip process has finished and then use the "doneFileName" URI option of the File2 component in your second route?

Comment: tx, used this solution. Can't figure why i missed it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `readLock` and `readLockInterval` parameters in the [File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) component.

Comment: The `readLock` parameter is for individual files, in this case I want to read only when all files are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can pickup one file at a time in route 1 with maxMessagesPerPoll=1, and then use the control bus component to stop the route, and then from the other route, start the route again.
http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html

Comment: do you have an example on how to use it in Spring DSL?